# Scrolling issue only with chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, scroll

I used the CSS property `scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;` to make a "step by step" scrolling effect on this box (scroll inside "AGIT" section) :
https://wikirouge.net/Accueil

It works fine with Firefox and Edge, but with Chrome, it always scrolls one line more than needed. If I use the scroll buttons instead of the mousewheel, it works fine.

Do you have an explanation, and a possible workaround?
Thanks

Comment: I can not spot any difference whatsoever in a current Chrome on Win10, both scrolling via mouse wheel and via scrollbar buttons, work exactly the same.

Comment: And yet it moves [diferently]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to conflict with transform declarations, after removing it, looks normal to me:

```
.content > * {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.6s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.6s ease;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was in particular this one that caused conflict `  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);`